# deleted mount from bin

Tags: mount, restore, slackware

I accidentally deleted "mount" from my dstro(Slackware 13.1). How can I restore it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This tool comes with the `util-linux` package. Use e.g. `pkgtool` to install it.